# Cryptopp RSA key generation

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

I generate pair RSA keys:

```
    InvertibleRSAFunction params;
    params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 4096);
    publicKey.Initialize(params.GetModulus(), params.GetPublicExponent());
    privateKey.Initialize(params.GetModulus(), params.GetPublicExponent(), params.GetPrivateExponent());
```

But if I want to do it next time and use the new pair in the decryption function, it works. The text will be decrypted. How to fix that in Cryptopp? (I am using raw RSA encryption / decryption)

Comment: Where is `rng` declared? Can you post complete example to reproduce?

Comment: @pptaszni `AutoSeededRandomPool rng;` is located above this piece of code, `privateKey.CalculateInverse(rng, c)`, where c is Integer - this function returns the same answer for different private keys

Comment: Sorry, if it works, then what is your question? What does "it works" mean?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I generate a key pair, encrypt it using the public key from this pair. Then I generate a new key pair and try to decrypt with a private key from the new pair and it works, the original text is obtained

Comment: If you have problems with that you need to provide a [mcve], because it is extremely unlikely that RSA is at fault.